# Read function body from a function passed as argument at runtime

Tags: go

I have some dynamic code generated and compiled - then I need to read function body  at runtime, is that possible?

```
package example

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

type TestStruct struct {}

func (TestStruct) New() *TestStruct {
    return &TestStruct{}
}

// CreateFunction func
func (t *TestStruct) CreateFunction(runFunc func(args []string)) {
    // Read code block, switch values from function pointer
    //val := reflect.ValueOf(t)....?
    fmt.Println(val[0]) // << read switch string option "one"
    fmt.Println(val[1]) // << read switch string option "two"
}

// Testing
func TestReflection(t *testing.T) {
    TestStruct{}.New().CreateFunction(func(args []string) {
        sw := "one"
        switch sw {
        case "one":
            fmt.Println("some text")
        case "two":
            fmt.Println("some text")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Because Go code is typically compiled to machine code, analyzing the code at runtime will be challenging.  There is not at reflect API for accessing the code.

Comment: Ok thanks @gopher

Answer (score 1):

If it is for testing purposes, the following code is feasible. I just printed out the body of function, you could try to parse the `SwitchStmt` in function body and get what you need.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "reflect"
    "runtime"
    "testing"
)

type TestStruct struct{}

func (TestStruct) New() *TestStruct {
    return &TestStruct{}
}

type FindBlockByLine struct {
    Fset  *token.FileSet
    Line  int
    Block *ast.BlockStmt
}

func (f *FindBlockByLine) Visit(node ast.Node) ast.Visitor {
    if node == nil {
        return nil
    }

    if blockStmt, ok := node.(*ast.BlockStmt); ok {
        stmtStartingPosition := blockStmt.Pos()
        stmtLine := f.Fset.Position(stmtStartingPosition).Line
        if stmtLine == f.Line {
            f.Block = blockStmt
            return nil
        }
    }
    return f
}

// CreateFunction func
func (t *TestStruct) CreateFunction(runFunc func(args []string)) {
    p := reflect.ValueOf(runFunc).Pointer()
    fc := runtime.FuncForPC(p)
    // get filename and line number of runFunc
    filename, line := fc.FileLine(p)
    fset := token.NewFileSet()
    // parse file to AST tree
    node, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, filename, nil, parser.ParseComments)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // walk and find the function block
    find := &FindBlockByLine{Fset: fset, Line: line}
    ast.Walk(find, node)

    if find.Block != nil {
        fp, err := os.Open(filename)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer fp.Close()
        fp.Seek(int64(find.Block.Lbrace-1), 0)
        buf := make([]byte, int64(find.Block.Rbrace-find.Block.Lbrace))
        _, err = io.ReadFull(fp, buf)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Println("code of runFunc:", string(buf))
    }
    // Read code block, switch values from function pointer
    // val := reflect.ValueOf(t)....?
    // fmt.Println(val[0]) // << read switch string option "one"
    // fmt.Println(val[1]) // << read switch string option "two"
}

// Testing
func TestReflection(t *testing.T) {
    TestStruct{}.New().CreateFunction(func(args []string) {
        sw := "one"
        switch sw {
        case "one":
            fmt.Println("some text")
        case "two":
            fmt.Println("some text")
        }
    })
}
```

output:

```
$ go test -v -run TestReflection
=== RUN   TestReflection
/xxxxxxxxxx.go 82
code of runFunc: {
        sw := "one"
        switch sw {
        case "one":
            fmt.Println("some text")
        case "two":
            fmt.Println("some text")
        }

--- PASS: TestReflection (0.00s)
PASS
ok      maint   0.501s
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a good suggestion - but I need it to be on runtime - if possible